# summing dict value of list to single integer

Tags: python

I am trying to do something pretty simple but cant seem to get it. I have a dictionary where the value is a list. I am trying to just sum the list and assign the value back to the same key as an int. Using the code below the first line doesn't do anything, the second as it says puts the value back but in a list. All other things ive tried has given me an error can only assign iterable. As far as i know iterables are anything that can be iterated on such as list and not int. Why can I only use iterable and how can i fix this issue ? The dict im using is here (https://gist.github.com/ishikawa-rei/53c100449605e370ef66f1c06f15b62e)

```
for i in dict.values():
    i = sum(i)
    #i[:] = [sum(i) / 3600] # puts answer into dict but as a list
```

Comment: this won't  work since the values don't point to keys.  and the keys would still pount to the original values.  also since you are iterating the the values, it's generally not good practice to modify what's being iterated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use simple dictionary comprehension if your dict values are all lists

```
{k:sum(v) for k, v in dict.items()}
```

Comment: this solution creates a new dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in dikt.keys():
    dickt[i] = sum(dict[i]))
```

btw, dict is a type.  best not to use it as a variable name